# No operating system

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, livedvd

I was upgrading my laptop (HP Pavilion dv6000) from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and the power failed.  Now I have no operating system `stops at "checking battery state   [OK]`

I'm sending this message from my desktop.  Would it be possible to download 14.04 to my desktop (without installing it), copying the download to a CD-ROM, and booting up the laptop from the CD-ROM?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Short answer is: It would be possible to load a liveboot CD/USB. Are you looking for further clarification on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

your upgrade is most likely ruined, and your files are most likely lost. But I would create a live-CD/USB and boot it. This is to see if your files are still there so you can make a backup.
Click on *try Ubuntu* and then try to mount the hard drive/SSD and make a backup of your files. then I would make a clean install.

You might be able to fix the broken upgrade but it will take **a lot of time** if it's possible at all. And you might end up with a really slow system. So just make a clean install.

See this question for more info

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your installation is botched.  What you can try doing before reinstalling the operating system is physically removing the battery from your laptop while the laptop is plugged into the AC Adapter.  Hypothetically, the OS should skip the check after determining that the battery isn't present.

Additionally, if you want to try and restore the operating system, create a boot disk on a CD: [How to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

As long as you don't format your hard drive when you install, the install will just correct/replace/install the system critical files and hopefully save your files.  As a precaution, I'd boot as a live disk first and try and save any files you have.